# how to move a site with absolute references to a subdirectory

Tags: language-agnostic

I inherited a site with absolute references, including absolute pointers to images within the CSS, such as background: url("/images/logo.png")

I have the need to run the site in the development environment from a sub-directory. Is there a way I can do something magical and have the site run properly even though the references are absolute

so instead of running within http://mySite.com it has to run in

http://mydevServer/subDirectory

I'm running LAMP

thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the best way is to use Apache Virtual Hosts to go directly to the subdirectory.